# Effective version of a lemma of Faltings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This question is about Lemma 2.3 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02721, the lemma is attributed to G. Faltings.

The statement is:

Let $K$ be a number field and let $S$ be a finite set of places containing all archimedean places. Let $p$ be a rational prime such that no place of $S$ lies above $p$. Let $w,d$ be non-negative integers. There are, up to conjugation, only finitely many semisimple Galois representations $\rho : G_K \rightarrow \text{GL}_d(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ such that

1) $\rho$ is unramified outside of $S$; and

2) $\rho$ is pure of weight $w$, that is, for every prime $\mathfrak{p} \not \in S$ all the eigenvalues of Frobenius at $\mathfrak{p}$ are algebraic numbers, all of whose conjugates have absolute value $q_{\mathfrak{p}}^{w/2}$, where $q_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the cardinality of the residue field of the completion of $K$ at $\mathfrak{p}$.

(Statement is slightly different from the original text for clarity and for notational completeness).

They cited the original paper of Faltings and a book chapter due to Wustholz. I currently don't have access to a copy of the latter, and the former is written in German, which I am not able to read. Therefore at the moment I cannot consult the sources.

My question is, for certain relatively simple fields $K$ (it seems for the application they want in their paper, the smallest field one can take $K$ to be is $\mathbb{Q}(\varpi)$, where $\varpi$ is a primitive 8th root of unity) and an explicit $S$ (when $K = \mathbb{Q}(\varpi)$, say $S$ consists of the infinite places and say all primes above a small rational prime, say 5 or something), and $p$ another small prime (say $p = 7$) can one give an effective, maybe even explicit bound for the finitely many semisimple Galois representations that are considered in the lemma?

Comment: The proof is a (straightforward) application of Chebotarev's theorem, so sure enough, it is an effective (in principle) result. You may easily make it explicit (if you need this) with the corresponding effective Chebotarev bound; of course, on GRH the result will be dramatically stronger. Besides, you don't need to follow German if you have an access to the 1985 Storrs volume (*Arithmetic Geometry*, ed. Cornell and Silverman), where the *Endlichkeitsatze* paper is included in an English translation. Faltings's argument appears inside the proof of Theorem 5, on page 23 of that volume.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the English translation of Faltings' paper in the Cornell and Silverman volume. However upon reading the chapter I realized that the original statement of Theorem 5 is about isogeny classes of abelian varieties over a fixed number field rather than semisimple Galois representations. To me it is not clear how these two are related. Is there a reference for that?

Comment: The statement yes, but given what Faltings had proved by that point in this paper (Theorems 3 and 4 of the preceding section), the Tate module is a fully faithful functor from abelian varieties mod isogenies to isomorphy classes of semisimple Galois representations. This functor is not, of course, essentially surjective; but the argument for Theorem 5 is really about the associated Galois representation (you may ignore the abelian variety, and the previous material of the paper). A secondary source may help: have a look at Theorem 4.3 on page 113 of Lang's *Number Theory III* survey volume.